# How Do I Pull Text From A Site And Then Put It In An Array

Tags: python, arrays, file, web, web-scraping

I've been wondering- how do I pull the text off a site then shove it in an array? At the moment I'm trying something like this:
https://hastebin.com/vokoxixaqo.lua

I want to store each site separately in an array so I can read from it one by one. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

````
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()
text = soup.get_text()
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("'\'"))
finaletext = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
with open('sites.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
    json.dump(finaletext, outfile)



sites = []

f = open('sites.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split('\n')
    for w in words:
        sites.append(w)
f.close()

print(sites)```
````

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: I’m not getting an error, I just want to be able to pull the text and put it into an array so I can use the list of sites and check if they’re added to the hosts file. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I'm very confused by your explanation. Do you keep text of sites in your host file? Also, what do you consider an array? Because in your example you made 3 already, so adding 1 more shouldn't be to difficult for you?

Comment: Alright what I’m trying to do is pull just the text from the site and it continues reading with \‘s everywhere. Then I want to assign the text to a different line in the text file for each refinement so it can be read into an array separately and neatly.

Comment: Best update your initial question with this information and perhaps provide a simple example handmade output. This way people know how to help you.